# Typescript/Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, horizon

I'm all the time learning. My question is: why this:

```
let user = {
   firstname: '',
   secondname: ''
}

let hz = new Horizon({host: "164.132.192.28:3100"});
let table = hz('users');
hz.connect();
table.find(1).fetch().subscribe((value) => { 
   user = {
     firstname: value.firstname,
     secondname: value.secondname
   }

   //OR: 
   user.firstname = value.firstname;
   user.secondname = value.secondname;

});

console.log(user);
```

gives me this:

[image: ...]

And why I can't get value?:

```
console.log(user.firstname);
//prints nothing
```

My third question: how to just save the results from query into an object and use it outside the query? If I use 'return' keyword then results are similar. I know it's a newbie question but I'm really struggling with this... Can someone help me?

Comment: This question is being asked twice a day. console.log(user) is executed immediately after you **create** an **asynchronous** request. A long time after, when the response finally comes back, then the code inside the callback function passed to subscribe() is executed. That's why you need to pass a callback function. If the call was synchronous, it would return the data directly, and wouldn't bother you with observables and callacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line:

```
table.find(1).fetch().subscribe(...);
```

is calling asynchronous method. This means that provided callback will be called sometime later and not immediately at the moment when `subscribe` is called. Therefore when it comes to `console.log()` the browser prints out its string representation and at that moment both first and last name are have not yet being populated - thus empty fields. When later you click on the object to see its content in console - browser evaluates it at that moment and most likely the subscribe method has already finished - so you get your first and last name present.

Your code is actually saves data in the local `user` variable. The thing you must remember is that you should access it only after `subscribe` callback has been called.